# How to store credit card in Paypal Vault without using the server as a proxy

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

We are using Paypal vault to store credit cards. (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/) this goes like this:

1) Ajax call from browser to server
2) Server sends request with accessToken to Paypal
3) Paypal responds with a token

So: User browser -> our server -> Paypal -> our server

Because of new internal policy I need to remove the 2nd step. So, I should go from the users browser to Paypal, receive the token, store the token

User browser -> Paypal -> User browser -> our server

Any thoughts on that?

**UPDATE:**
Would it be safe to send the access token through the browser? (I can create it on the server)
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Comment: I think publishing your access token might not be the best idea.

Comment: Exactly, so I thought, would it be possible to create a new access token per request and remove it when the request is done...?

Comment: I don't think that makes sense. Your access token is the thing that identifies your application to PayPal servers. Making up a new access token would mean that you're making up a new application. You can't keep things secret if you're doing it from code you send out to client web browsers.

Comment: Of course, but I need to send this: `'Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}'` the `{accessToken}` is *not* the key, it's a token created with the key, so that's something I could do serverside...

Comment: 2nd point here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Comment: OK, well that's good. The next thing that'd be required will be for the PayPal URLs to be set up to allow access from your domain. I don't know whether that's possible. If they don't do that, then the browser won't allow the HTTP requests to be made from JavaScript.